# How can I export a blur image?

Tags: export, sketch-app, blur

I am using Sketch to create my design. I have created a view that is blurred. So if I put it on any other image, it will make it blurred.

Now I want to export this blur, but I seem to be unable to do so. When I try to export the blur, its just gives me a white image or the actually blurred image, but not something that blurs the image that is behind it.

How can I export this blur?

[image: Middle view is blur]